# Passing data from controller to another controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am working on sails JS application.

Is there anyway to pass a data from another controller using sails JS?

```
  // controller 1
  exports.module{
     passing data to controller 2
  }

  // controller2 

  exports.module{
     get data from controller 1
  }
```

or better, is there anyway to create a global variable which can be accessed by any controller in sails js? just like $_SESSION['sessionname'] in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Service](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/services), it enables you to access data everywhere in your code.

**EDIT**

You can also use the global variable `sails`:

> sails.myObject = {}

Comment: thanks man. btw, is there a possible way to pass a value there?

Comment: You can also use `sails.myObject = { }`

Answer (score 0):

I will assume there are two Controller as you have asked in your question.

Subject Controller (which returns the data)

```
module.exports = {
  science : function (req, res, next, callback) {
    var data = ["Biology", "Physics", "Chemistry"];
    return callback(data);
  }
}
```

Student Controller (which receives the data)

```
module.exports = {
  getStudentSubject : function(req, res, next, callback){
    //get the data from Subject controller
    sails.controllers.subject.science(req, res, next, function(data){
      // got the data
      console.log(data)
      // this should print ["Biology", "Physics", "Chemistry"]
    });
  }
}
```

Any controller method can be accessed in sails by **sails.controllers.methodName**

Hope this helps.